# In what way do Object-Relational databases provide limited inferencing, when compared to the use of Ontologies?

Tags: relational-database, ontology, object-oriented-database

I'm currently working on modeling context for a context-aware application.
The better choice seems to be ontologies, however object oriented models and relation data bases, seem to have some advantages too.

An author (Jagdev Bhogal and Philip Moore) in particular used object-relational databases to model context and claim that:

> The  ORDBMS  approach  provides  limited  inferencing.  A subtype
>   definition has access to the representation of all of its direct 
>   supertypes (but  only  within  the  ADT  definition  that   defines 
>   the  subtype  of  that  supertype), but it has no access to the
>   representation of its sibling types. 〈…〉  Such functionality would
>   need to be manually  programmed when developing the  application
>   interface.

I'm new to this subject, and it seems to me that you could make very complex queries to retrieve almost any information, but I've never used ontologies before.

So: in what way do object-relational databases, or even regular relational databases, provide limited inferencing, when compared to the use of ontologies (e.g.  OWL Description Logic)?

Comment: Inferencing in a relational db typically means the DBMS inferring what rows satisfy a query's asociated characteristic predicate about stuff assuming that base variables' rows satisfy their associated characteristic predicates about stuff. Normally the stuff is the application. Inferencing in any other data structure must be programmed based on how you decide to represent stuff. An object-relational database is essentially a relational database where the base predicates are trivially about the values of object states, which somehow represent the application, rather than about the application.

Comment: These authors likely mean something different. You need to find out what they are summarizing by 'inferencing'. So you need to give a lot of details about what they are doing. However, this question is off-topic on [so]. See [ask] and other [help] links. Maybe this could be on-topic at another [se] site or maybe you could make this specific enough to be so.